# Does LogonExchangeMailbox log into other mailboxes than the specified one?

Tags: exchange-server, outlook-redemption

I am using the `RDOSession.LogonExchangeMailbox` method from the Outlook Redemption library to log into a specific mailbox on exchange server that the current user has access to but that does not necessarily belong to the current user.

If the current user has access to multiple mailboxes, does this method guarantee that only the specified mailbox will be included in `RDOSession.Stores`? Or is there a chance that other mailboxes (that the user has access to, or even the mailbox for the user himself) will be populated as stores inside `RDOSession.Stores`?

In summary, can I guarantee that `RDOSession.Stores[1]` will always point to the mailbox specified in the `LogonExchangeMailbox` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LogonExchangeMailbox (Exchange 2010 or older) always creates a temporary profile that points to the specified mailbox. It is not however guaranteed that RDOSession.Stores[1] will point to the primary mailbox - you can also have a PF store in the profile and the order is undetermined. Use `RDOSession.Stores.DefaultStore` instead.

Comment: So `RDOSession.Stores.DefaultStore` will always point to the mailbox specified by the `User` parameter when invoking `LogonExchangeMailbox` even if the user that is executing the code is a different user. Right?